# HTML form using Python 3

Tags: forms, python-3.x

I wanted to post a HTML form on a site using Python 3.

Say for http://www.example.com/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`urllib.request` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.request).

You just need to figure out what the field names of the form are, and set up your request with the appropriate data.  There are examples on the page using both PUT and GET methods.

Answer (score 0):

Python’s standard urllib and urllib2 module provides most of the HTTP capabilities you need, but the API is thoroughly broken. It was built for a different time — and a different web. It requires an enormous amount of work (even method overrides) to perform the simplest of tasks.

Instead we can use [Requests module](http://python-requests.org/%E2%80%8E) for python which simplifies the process.
Here is the quick start guide[Quick-start guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html)